# Creating the Shared Library File from a C File

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to create a shared library file (.so extension) from my C file to call my C function from Python. I found several websites saying that we can use the following command to do so:

```
 cc -fPIC -shared -o my_functions.so my_functions.c
```

However, I am not sure where I need to run this command. I tried running this on the terminal of Visual Studio Code but got the following error:

```
> PS C:\Users\me\Documents\CProgramming\0903_> cc -fPIC -shared -o my_functions.so my_functions.c
cc : The term 'cc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1 
+ cc -fPIC -shared -o my_functions.so my_functions.c
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Does anyone know what is the correct way or correct platform to run this command? For a note, I am using Windows. This is the website I referred to: https://www.journaldev.com/31907/calling-c-functions-from-python

Comment: On linux, `cc` is frequently an alias to `gcc`. Since you are running on Windows, you want a .dll, not an .so, so you need to look for different examples. But since you are using Visual Studio Code, which has a C/C++ compiler, just use it. Search for how to use VSC to compile a dll. That's what you are after.

Comment: Thanks, @tdelaney! I successfully converted the file into .dll file. However, I got an error when trying to load the .dll file by CDLL function on Python. I will post another question regarding this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cc` is the compiler command. Your current shell (Powershell) can not find `cc` in your Path.

You either need to install a compiler (i.e. gcc) or add the compiler you have installed in your system to your Path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tyed 'gcc --version' on cmd and found the gcc is already installed. Do you know how to get the path to the gcc?

Comment: try re-running the command which failed but replace `cc` with `gcc`

Comment: I thought I needed to set the path but didn't have to! It worked after replacing it with ``gcc``. Thanks a lot!